# Cooling pad for 2015 Macbook Pro 15"?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware-recommendation, cooling

There's a [thread about the 2011 model](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/52989/74706), but it doesn't have an answer and that was a lot of technology ago.

A lot of people have said that the [macbook will handle it's own cooling process](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/121846/74706), but mine is new and will get pretty hot within half an hour of watching movies or mid-level processing.  I think I'd like something if only to provide a layer of ventilation and buffer between myself and the computer.

- Does anyone have any experience actually getting a cooling pad for their mac?
- Is it really not worth it to spend twenty bucks to provide better ventilation?
- If you think it's worth it, any specific recommendations on products?

Comment: Since it is new and under warranty, let them check if anything wrong with it. I can watch movies for hours without heating up on my 2012 MacBook Air.

Comment: you can always back the kickstarter for this cooler: http://www.madminds.com/pages/tilt-stealth-retina-wait-list
#no-i-do-not-work-for-them

Answer (score 2):

## Make One

See [my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/198396/17907) on a similar Question.

Boost your laptop with a Roost, and add a 4" fan from BestBuy.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you get a laptop stand like the Roost, you're money will give you an ergonomic benefit as well as a thermal one.

Answer (score 1):

Laptops are designed to be able to handle high internal temperatures and the fact that the body heats up and the fans come on when performing processor-intensive tasks is not a problem (in fact, it's by design). That said, due to limited space the internal fans are tiny and high RPM, making them quite noisy and possibly quite annoying (depending of course on your tolerance for fan noise!).

A cooling pad can be useful for a few reasons:

- They have larger, lower RPM fans - lower noise than the internal laptop fans
- Some have adjustable fan speeds - again, lower noise
- They may have other features, like the ability to elevate your laptop

The key feature for me is the low RPM fans - they can be near silent and prevent the laptop's internal fans from going on. As you say, for $20 you've got nothing to lose! I have a cheap [Avantek](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00UKPW39G) cooler and it works nicely - most of the time it stops my MacBook's fans from going on and it's near silent.

Comment: So you are having one of the Avantek Pads? And you are sure there is a cooling effect? Just wondering, because my mac is going to 100C (during intense compiling or rendering sessions). And i thought of getting such a cooling pad, but i read that with the ventilation system of the mac its not worth spending that money